# Why did the Stargate cover stones have the gate address to Abydos on them?

Tags: stargate

In the movie Stargate it is revealed that ancient Egyptians rebelled against Ra and kicked him off of Earth. They then buried the stargate and crafted a set of elaborately decorated cover stones for it.
But seeing as how they had just thrown off their oppressor, Ra, and sent him packing, why did they add the gate address for Abydos to the cover stones knowing that it had to be someplace Ra would likely turn up at?

Comment: In the movie they missed the warning "Whatever you do DO NOT go here:"

Comment: maybe they hoped that eventually someone with a nuke would uncover the gate, go there, and blow the guy up?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Within the movie itself - there isn't really a lot of explanation. We barely see the uprising against Ra.

However, if you want to place the movie in the same universe as the series, then we have an explanation in Moebius (Season 8 finale):

> The uprising against Ra was helped by members of the SGC who had travelled back in time - in order to create a closed loop, they could have put the symbols on the coverstone knowing about the original Abydos mission allowing them to get there at the right time in the 1990s.

Comment: Seems as if the series creators realized there was a plot point dangling from the movie and graciously tied it up.

Comment: No, this doesn't work. The coverstones in the original timeline had the Abydos address too. It's a common misconception, for some reason, that SG-1 had always been responsible for the original Egyptian uprising; were that the case, the entire show would have been set in the timeline where a ZPM were found at Giza. The fact is that, until the end of Moebius, we're following a timeline in which SG-1 were _not_ present during the uprising.

Comment: (Note, in particular, the fish in Jack's pond.)

Answer (score 4):

The answer is in the movie though perhaps not spelled out; it was the one system they knew of that had people taken from their community.  Hope of the two halves of their culture being united and free is at least implied in the film.